# how to create a setup or installer file and adding MYSQL reference using visual studio C# and MYSQL for deploy my project into another system?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm develop a new project for Medical Laboratory by using visual studio C# WinForms for user interaction and MYSQL for database. After my successful build its running successfully in my windows machine. But the problem is when I install my project on another windows machine, the front end of UI running well but the database throw an error to me. The error is **Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'login'**. I think the error was I need to add MYSQL reference in my project. but I'm absolutely don't know how to do it. I'm really sorry to all coz I'm noob in C# and my English.
and literally thanks to all.

```
public partial class registration : Form
{
  string connectionstring = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = login; password = 
  qwerty;";
  MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
  MySqlCommand cmd;
  connection.Open();
  try
   {
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE register ADD UNIQUE INDEX(rgstrid);";
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT IGNORE INTO register(username, password,confirm) VALUES(@username,@password,@confirm)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rgstrusrnmtxtbx.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rgstrpswdtxtbx.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@confirm", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = rgstrcnfrmtxtbx.Text;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(table);
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Your Account resgistred Successfully", "information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
         }
         else
         {
               MessageBox.Show("Account saved Successfully","Success",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             throw;
         }
         finally
         {
              if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
              {
                  connection.Close();
              }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include a reference to a library to talk to MySql, like the [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/) package. Adding it as a nuget reference should ensure the required files are installed with the rest of the application files.

Your installer also needs to install some software. The database engine itself if you are running a local database, but also a [.net connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) for the ado.net driver.

At least this is how we do it. You might be able to avoid some components depending how you are accessing the database.

When installing the database you should specify the root password. For example by giving the `rootpasswd=qwerty` parameter to the MySQLInstallerConsole.exe program.

Your install script also needs to setup the database, i.e. either run sql files to create any tables and fill it with data, or copy the database files themselves, or run some program to create the tables.

Comment: yeah thank you, I'm adding mysql reference from nuget package but im still getting an error.

Comment: @Pradeep Well, is the database & connector installed? Can you login with the workbench with the specified login?

Comment: yeah i'm installed my database and connector. The login works very well in my windows machine

Comment: @Pradeep if the login works on *your* machine is irrelevant. It should work on the *target* machine after the installer has run.

Comment: but the target machine throws an error **Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'login'**

Comment: @Pradeep that is either because the password is invalid, or that the login database has not been created. Your install script should both specify root password and create any necessary databases & tables. Again, install the mysql workbench on the target computer after the install script has run, and check what has actually been installed.

Comment: okay !!! ill check and notify to you what really happen ... : )